# Probability of $E$ when $F$ has happened - three coins tossed

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

In conditional probability example where 3 fair coins are tossed, the sample space is:

> HHH, HTH, HHT, THH, THT, TTH, TTT, HTT

$E$ be an event where at least two heads appear, $F$ be an event where the first coin yields a Tail. Now $P(E|F)$ warrants the cases satisfying event $F$ to act as a sample space for event $E$.

It is worded "probability of $E$ when $F$ has happened" - if $F$ has happened then $E$ can also happen separately after event $F$ is over, then there won't be any need for altering the sample space. Why is it not like that?

Comment: I'm a downvoter:  Here are just some of my reasons:  1) The title is nearly useless... there is no way the reader understands what $E$ and $F$ refer to.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That is why the question has an explanation part.

Comment: Your "explanation part" says nothing whatsoever about what $E$ and $F$ are... See?  No "explanation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that the event F has happened, that only means that on tossing the first coin we get a Tail, now the statement:

> probability of E when F has happened

means that first coin got tail, now what is the probability of event E i.e. getting two heads?

Now if you got tail in the first go, then you are left with only two coins to toss, the sample space has now been altered & that would be a decisive factor in calculating probability for event E.

Sample space for F = THH, THT, TTH, TTT -> now only in once case the event E is satisfied, hence the probability is 1/4.

Answer (score 1):

> It is worded "probability of E when F has happened" - if F has happened then E can also happen separately after event F is over, then there won't be any need for altering the sample space. Why is it not like that?

You are providing a reasonable interpretation of the sentence in English, which does not represent the intent of the author.

Probability of E when F has happened is actually intended to have one of the following two meanings, neither of which is consistent with your interpretation:

- Probability that E has occurred given that F has occurred.  This means that it is presumed that the trial representing whether the event E occurred or not took place at the exact same time that the event F occurred.
- Probability that *when* F occurs (at some point in the future) when the trial of event E **simultaneously** occurs, event E will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

P(E|F) is a conditional probability or the event that Event E happens given Event F. This is the same as $\frac{|E \cap F|}{|F|}$

There are $2^2$ outcomes for Event F. THH is the only outcome for at least two heads given that the first flip is T.
You would get $\frac{1}{4}$

Note:
I'm pretty sure this is different than P(E $\cap$ F) which would be $\frac{|E \cap F|}{|S|}$, where S is the sample space.

Comment: I know the answer but the question is different.